# ImportXML Error: Imported XML content can not be parsed

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

The formula does not work properly on certain pages I guess.

I could load products name and prices, only different with URLs and class names, from the below method.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://mall.han-don.com/goods/goods_list.php?cateCd=001002","//*[@class='prdName']//text()")
```

However, it's not loaded with 'Imported XML content can not be parsed.' message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://mall.han-don.com/goods/goods_list.php?cateCd=001002"), 10000, 1), """", ), 
 "where Col1 contains 'strong class=prdName>'"), ">(.+)</strong"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({{"";"";SUBSTITUTE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://mall.han-don.com/goods/goods_list.php?cateCd=001002"), 10000, 1), """", )}, 
 {ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://mall.han-don.com/goods/goods_list.php?cateCd=001002"), 10000, 1);"";""}}, 
 "select Col2 where Col1 contains 'span class=cost prdPrice'")&".000원")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow Amazing! I guess IMPORTDATA formula is more stable than the IMPORTXML. I'll get use to with that! thanks a lot!!